# Bootstrap Fileinput cannot hide progress bar (nodejs/Electron)

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, electron

I am creating an Electron project and I am using Bootstrap Fileinput.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Folder containing installation/patch scripts</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input id="input-2" name="input2" type="file" class="file" data-show-upload="false" data-show-preview="false" data-show-cancel="false" webkitdirectory>
    </div>
</div>
```

The control is rendered fine and works. The issue is that, as soon as the control is rendered, I can see "0%" above it. No matter what I have tried I cannot remove that. I don't want a progress bar to be visible, the control will work only to locate a folder name, which will then be used for other purposes.

Any ideas why I always see the progress bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to add the following option in js code when I create fileinput:

```
layoutTemplates: {progress: ''}
```